# ON DUPLICATE KEY ignoring ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to perform an INSERT to MySQL server to avoid "reading" the table twice, that is why I do the following query:

```
INSERT INTO dailykpi
(
    kpiType,
    kpiRowType,
    kpiRowTypeValue,
    kpiYear,
    kpiWeek,
    kpiValue
) 
VALUES 
(
    $kpiType,
    $kpiRowType,
    $sat,
    $currentYear,
    $currentWeek,
    $value
)
```

And if the registry already exists (and it will everyday until the end of a week), I update the values:

```
INSERT INTO dailykpi
(
    kpiType,
    kpiRowType,
    kpiRowTypeValue,
    kpiYear,
    kpiWeek,
    kpiValue
)
VALUES 
(
    $kpiType,
    $kpiRowType,
    $sat,
    $currentYear,
    $currentWeek,
    $value
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    kpiType = $kpiType, 
    kpiRowType = $kpiRowType, 
    kpiRowTypeValue = $sat, 
    kpiYear = $currentYear, 
    kpiWeek = $currentWeek, 
    kpiValue = $value
```

But it is still inserting duplicates entries. I guessed it is because of my auto_increment ID column, that is always different, but I guess as well that is so trivial to lack SQL like that, so maybe I am missing something.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the ID is an auto_incrementable INT PRIMARY KEY, the rest of columns are INT (one foreign key) and one of them is FLOAT, no one is unique key or any of that, should they?

Comment: What combination of columns comprises a unique set? All of them (except the auto-increment)? You need to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on those columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is:

```
INSERT INTO dailykpi(kpiType, kpiRowType, kpiRowTypeValue, kpiYear, kpiWeek, kpiValue)
    VALUES ($kpiType, $kpiRowType, $sat, $currentYear, $currentWeek, $value)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE kpiType=$kpiType, kpiRowType=$kpiRowType, 
                            kpiRowTypeValue=$sat, kpiYear=$currentYear, 
                            kpiWeek=$currentWeek, kpiValue=$value;
```

Note you had a final closing parenthesis that was superfluous.

For this to work, you need a unique index/constraint to define the duplicate key.  For instance, you might have one row per `kpiYear`, `kpiWeek` and `pkiType`.  If so, you can create the unique index as:

```
create unique index idx_dailykpi_3 on dailykpi(kpiYear, kpiWeek, kpiType);
```

Comment: I forgot to delete the parenthesis, it came from php code, sorry.

I tried this but it just inserted few rows, so I added kpiValue to te unique index, because actually what I want to do everyday is to check if there is a value for that kpiRow, kpiRowValue, Year and Week and update the value. And if it does not exist, then insert the complete row. I don't know why it is not working properly :S

Thanks a million

Comment: @Zoudan . . . It is best to have only one unique index when using `on duplicate key update`.  Delete the first index and only use the one you really want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still wondering... if I remove primary key actually there is no problem since I don't use it as foreign key from other table, but which one/s should I establish as unique index?. I think my brain is starting to short out, sorry if it is a stupid question.

Comment: And also... Would I lose the "auto_increment"? Thanks!

Comment: @Zoudan . . . An auto-incremented primary key is fine.  You can have that as well as another combination of unique keys (this is because you are not inserting the value of the primary key, so there is no confusion on the duplicates).  So, keep the auto-incremented primary key *and* define the combination of unique keys.

Comment: Just as you said. Just THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining the next unique index:

create unique index idx_dailykpi_5 on dailykpi(kpiYear, kpiWeek, kpiType, kpiRowType, kpiRowTypeValue);

Finally I didn't have to modify the primary key, so far is working as expected.

The thing was that I needed to check if the year, the week, the type, type of row and its value were the same, and then just update the value of that kpi:

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE kpiValue=$value

Thanks a million Gordon Linoff because you solved me the problem and now I can go on with this mini-project!